# How can I open multiple chromedrivers in a for loop with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I open multiple chromedrivers in a for loop with python selenium? I have the following code, but can't find a solution for this.

```
drivers=[driver1,driver2,driver3,driver4,driver5]
for x in drivers:
    x = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/a/Downloads/chromedriver')
    x.get('https://google.nl')
```

Comment: Can you try the suggestion in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45791791/5386938)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.

```
drivers=['driver1','driver2','driver3','driver4','driver5']
for x in drivers:
    x = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/a/Downloads/chromedriver')
    x.get('https://google.nl')
```

Or you can just provide the range.

```
for i in range(5):
    x = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/a/Downloads/chromedriver')
    x.get('https://google.nl')
```